# Limit problem: Find the valeu of $ a $ where the $ \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2+ax+a+3}{x^2+x-2}$ exists and find the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find the valeu of $\displaystyle a$  where the following limit exist and what is the $\displaystyle \lim$ valeu?

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3x^2+ax+a+3}{x^2+x-2}$

And also: I can´t use derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

There is a theorem about the limit of quotients, that goes something like this.

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous at $b$.
>
> - If $g(b) \ne 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(b)}{g(b)}$.
> - If $g(b) = 0$ and $f(b) \ne 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist.
> - If $f(b) = g(b) = 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ **may or may not** exist.

In this case, you know $g(b) = 0$.  So the *only way* for the limit to exist is if $f(b) = 0$ as well.

From there, you can decide what $a$ is.
Then, just to be sure you can make sure the limit exists at $a$.
To do so, you will probably have to cancel a common factor of $(x + 2)$ from the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the prove for the third statement?

Comment: @user3347814 Since the statement is "may or may not" exist, all you have to do is consider a couple examples.  Suppose $b = 0$.  Then the limit exists if $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$.  But the limit does not exist if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As the denominator vanishes at $x=-2$

the numerator must do so.

Comment: Indeed that leads to the right answer. Could you please elaborate on why that works?

Comment: @user3347814, $$\frac a0=?$$ for $a\ne0$ and $a=0$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, please? Since the denominator is zero, the limit shouldn´t exist, right?

Comment: @user3347814 Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1$ even though the denominator is zero.

Comment: @user3347814, the necessary condition is the numerator must $\to0$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
a rational function, whose domain is the set of the real numbers that are not roots of the denominator.

Let be $k$ a root of the denominator, i. e., $Q(k)=0$. If $P(k)\neq 0$, then the limit
$$\lim_{x\to k}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
is not finite.

But if $P(k)=0$, then the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ are both divisible by $x-k$, and hence the fraction can be 'simplified'. If $k$ is not a root $Q(x)/(x-k)$ anymore, the limit exists and is finite: just substitute in the simplified fraction.

Comment: I think your answer is more elegant, but I didn´t understand the part where you say that $P$ and $Q$ are divisible by $x-k$...